# Can we bypass SSL Pinning?

Tags: debugging, http-proxy

I want to intercept requests coming from the Dropbox app on macOS but it seems that it implement SSL Pinning. Is there any way to bypass this protocol?

Comment: Are you talking about a specific Dropbox client app? If so, which one?

Comment: Yes, I have tried testing Dropbox app on macOS but failed. Is there anyway to bypass SSL Pinning?